# How do I read CellFormat in google sheets api v4 in C#?

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need to read `row height`, `text color`, `font style` from some `cell`.  How can I do this? I found the `CellFormat` class, but how to get it from the api I could not find.

Comment: I just had a look at the API, and it is exactly what I would expect from google , half baked, disjointed, and sparse :/ I tried...

Comment: @TheGeneral :^(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything can be obtained from this `response`

```
String spreadsheetId = "<spreadsheetId>";
String range = "Rooms!A2:E";
var ranges = new List<string>() { range };
var request = service.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadsheetId);
request.Ranges = ranges;
request.IncludeGridData = true;
var response = request.Execute();
```